# Postsharp Multicast using Xml Ignore properties

Tags: postsharp

I was wondering if it was possible to apply aspects to everything using multicast (xml) except for class properties? At the moment I have something like this:

```
   <Multicast>
    <When Condition="{$LoggingEnabled}">
      <d:Log AttributeTargetTypes="Namespace.*"/>
    </When>
  </Multicast>
```

I realize that I have to `log` element, although I am not sure how. I tried `UserGenerated` but had no luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude *auto-implemented* properties from attribute application, then set `UserGenerated` in `AttributeTargetMemberAttributes`:

```
<Multicast>
  <When Condition="{$LoggingEnabled}">
    <d:Log AttributeTargetTypes="Namespace.*"
           AttributeTargetMemberAttributes="UserGenerated" />
  </When>
</Multicast>
```

If you also want to exclude *manually implemented* properties, then you would need to filter them out by name in a separate attribute application:

```
<Multicast>
  <When Condition="{$LoggingEnabled}">
    <d:Log AttributeTargetTypes="Namespace.*"
           AttributeTargetMemberAttributes="UserGenerated" />

    <d:Log AttributeTargetTypes="Namespace.*"
           AttributeExclude="true"
           AttributeTargetMembers="regex:^get_|^set_"  />

  </When>
</Multicast>
```

Comment: This was awesome... but can you tell me where in the xml schema in the psproj to apply the tags? For example, do I next it within the Project tag?